# Mongo $and query never returns any records

Tags: mongodb

I don't seem to be able to get any $and queries to return results in MongoDB. Here is a very simple example that I would expect to work. This is MongoDB v 2.0.4

> db.foo.insert({letter: 'a', number: 2})
>
> db.foo.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f8cbf5b19a4296c4255028e"), "letter" : "a", "number" : 2 }

> db.foo.find({letter: 'a'})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f8cbf5b19a4296c4255028e"), "letter" : "a", "number" : 2 }

> db.foo.find({letter: 'a', number: 2})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f8cbf5b19a4296c4255028e"), "letter" : "a", "number" : 2 }

// WHY DON"T ANY OF THESE RETURN RECORDS?

> db.foo.find({$and: [{letter: 'a', number: 2}]})
>
> db.foo.find({$and: [{letter: 'a'}, {number: 2}]})
>
> db.foo.find({$and: [{letter: 'a'}]})
>
> db.foo.find({$and: []})

Answer (score 0):

This was because I had an older version of Mongo prior to support for $and automatically starting on my system.

Mongo does not give a warning or error when connecting to different server versions or using unsupported keywords. I suggest it at least print the server version and a warning...